# text to column insert in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, logic

[image]

My sample input has three columns with id, name and houses. My desired output is just two columns id , guid. where I did a transpose of all the row data to column based on column id. using select all statement. My question is when I do this I have comma separated values. 
Is there a query I can use to to split these comma separated values and transpose

Comment: The answer is probably database-specific. What's the specific database engine?

Comment: I am using MySQL workbench